# Is the .NET Web API BadRequest() method equivalent to Request.CreateErrorResponse(...)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In our Web API at my company, we currently return our 400 error responses with the code:

```cs
return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, someErrorMessage);
```

However, in my personal projects with Web API and in some of the documentation, I have seen the much cleaner code for returning various status codes, such as:

```
return BadRequest(someErrorMessage);
```

What's the difference between these two methods of returning a 400 response? Which is preferred? Can we safely migrate from one variant to another without any difference in what the consumer of the API will see? We use Swagger, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

They are just different ways from different libraries for creating response messages and there is no different in the generated response.

In the code i suggest using ApiController built in methods like BadRequest(), InternalServerError() and Ok().

**But Some http status codes is not available in ApiController methods** like "406 Not Acceptable", "426 Upgrade Required" and etc, so you have to use another way like CreateErrorResponse() method Or you can extend ApiController and create your own methods for generating error responses that more used in your application.

Comment: The fact that some status codes are not available is not a major problem - we can implement the missing ones via a custom base controller class extending from ApiController or via extension methods. However, using `BadRequest()` does require that I change the return type of the method in C# meaning that the impact of switching is larger than I would like for our very large and business critical API.

Comment: Of course you can extend and in some large scale applications they do this and creates their own class for returning status codes that  more used in the application.